# IDEA sbt plugin can not auto import Predef

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

My IntelliJ IDEA vaersion is 139.463.4

when i use scala plugin to create sbt project, it can not auto import `Predef`, for example :

```
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("1")
  }
}
```

the `println`function is red highlight and hint can not resolve the symbol `println`,

I remember that `Predef` is auto import in scala. the above code runs ok by idea.

it's a sbt plugin bug?

Comment: is I should `import Preder._` in each scala file?

Comment: try reimporting the project and see if that fixes the error.

Comment: I have retry reimporting the project but can not fixes the error, I don't know what happend when I reinstall IDEA everything is ok. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "invalidate cache" under file menu.